# Generation of vector Grid For a Game

Tags: c++

I am working on a c++ project and I'm stuck. I am trying to generate a grid from a vector that holds what elements are in the grid. Originally, the vector will hold something like(3,3) and I would simply create a grid that looks like this XXX. If it were (3,2,1), it would be XX|X. The first number in the parenthesis represents the total number of X's that is in my Grid(even after an X has been removed) and the consequent number represents the number of X's for each column like shown above.

The problem I'm having is creating a grid that also keeps track of the removed X's so when I want to recreate it, the space for the removed X's is there and not overwritten.

For instance:  **Initial Grid** = XXX|XX  =>(5,3,2)
               **Later Grid**   = OOX|XX  => (3,1,2)

Generating a grid from the "**Initial Grid**" is simple but generating later grids are hard(for me). For instance, My new vector would hold (3,1,2) for the "**Later Grid**". If I want to generate the "Later Grid" using the (3,1,2) representation, how should I do it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is not a homework, this is a side project that I'm working on.

Comment: What attempts have you made at this? Please post some code and explain what its output is and how it differs from what you want.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. (3,1,2) does not uniquely identify OOX|XX, unless there is some logic behind the removals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would a two-dimensional array not suffice for your program? Say you declare a two-dimensional array of your max map size, then use two independent variables to represent the max grid size there after?

```
char Map[15][15] = {//...}
int Width = 15;
int Height = 15;

//Map decreases in size...
Width--;
Height--;
//all calculations are now based off of width and height(not the initial size of the array)

if(xpos < Width)
//do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you're working on a persistence problem.  I may not fully understand what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you will be reading a series of tuples in the form `(x:int, y:int, z:int)`
where

```
x = total number of 'X' 
y = 'X' before vertical bar
z = 'X' after vertical bar
```

then you want to pad missing 'X' with 'O'.

The problem it seems is that you are loosing information about the initial state of your grid and therefore don't know how many 'O' to pad with.

if I were you I would just add another value to keep track of the initial state.  This value would never change and would be populated with the initial number of 'X' when the grid is first generated.

so in your example you have:

**Initial Grid** = XXX|XX =>(5,3,2) **Later Grid** = OOX|XX => (3,1,2)

instead try adding an initial state value to the tuple like this

**Initial Grid** = XXX|XX =>(5,3,2,**5**) **Later Grid** = OOX|XX => (3,1,2,**5**)

now you have a tuple in the form `(x:int, y:int, z:int, n:int)` where

```
x = total number of 'X' 
y = 'X' before vertical bar
z = 'X' after vertical bar 
n = 'X' in initial state
```

now we can determine the number of 'O' to pad with by evaluating

```
n - x = number of 'O' to pad with
```

assuming that the initial number of 'X' varies from tuple to tuple  you would need to keep track of the initial 'X' state as well.  keeping track the initial number of 'X' will allow you to always discern how many 'O' you need to pad with for every successive iteration of the grid

Comment: I thought of that. So minutes ago I tried to use a vector that stores the initial state of my grid for instance when the function is called, the vector is instantiated with a 1's.When I remove an X from my original grid, I change the vector I just created. I just want to be able to recreate the grid knowing where the O's are.

Comment: @k.ken I think you're overthinking this. If you want to model a grid, then why not have a vector of strings, i.e. `{"OOX", "XX"}`?

Comment: yeah depending on what you are trying to do I think jrok's idea takes the cake on this one

Comment: jrok, when my program starts it creates a grid that is vector<char> Grid. The regeneration of a grid is done by a function that works recursively. Thanks for the suggestion though